# В чем смысл миграций

Tags: php, node.js, миграция

Здравствуйте!

Встречал инструменты для создания миграций, например artisan в Laravel или db-migrate для NodeJS, но никак не пойму их смысл, если, например, можно просто создать файл с sql запросами на создание таблиц и не мучаться.

Что скажете?

Comment: Конечно можно и sql файлики создать, если вашим сервисом пользуются полтора рудокопа и у вас одна табличка в базе данных.

Comment: @Suvitruf а можно примеры с конкретными возмоностями этих инструментов и проблемами которые они решаю, и, соответственно, которые не могут быть решены sql файликами

Comment: Можно сказать так: "Миграции" - это концепция, которая реализует систему контроля для вашей субд. Это концепцию можно реализовывать по разному, можно файликами, можно уже существующими инструментами и т.п. Самые очевидные плюсы миграции такие: 1) Те разработчики (если вы работаете в команде) которые не занимаются разработкой СУБД - могут легко понять новые изменения; 2) Можно сделать "быстрый откат" (Проекты с несколькими разрабами апдейтят продакшн "версиями", новые функционал - заливают "разом", а не кусками, и если патч вышел кривой можно разом откатить изменения, включая изменения субд).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Миграции нужны для того, чтобы через GIT или просто через файлы проекта передать изменения состояния БД

Вам проще руками что-то делать, а теперь ситуации:

**1.Командная работа**

- вы работаете не один!
- вы что-то поменяли в структуре (добавили, изменили) и отправили в GIT
- человек подтянул изменения и у него не работает, так как код написан под другую структуру БД

Не в чате же каждый раз пересылать инфу всем коллегам, что вы поменяли :)

**2. Работа с несколькими проектами на одной кодовой базе**

- вы работаете один, но локальный проект должен быть в 3 версиях на продакшне
- вы что-то поменяли и теперь вам в 3 местах нужно лазать и менять все это добро, особенно если изменений много

**3.Туда-сюда изменения**

- Вы сделали что-то не так в коде и решили вернуть структуру БД
- Вы ковыряете БД локальную, потом удаленную, когда могли просто
  набрать откат миграции

Я например в этих ситуациях бываю каждый час работы.

**Итог**

Миграции — передача состояния БД (с инструкциями отката состояний), которая гарантирована описана и может передваться через контроль версий или просто с кодом.

Откат или накат их можно добавить в автодеплой, и когда вы решили выкатить релиз, все само делается — гит подтянулся, миграции накатились, релиз выкатился

**Отдельное преимущество:**

Как правило имена миграций содержат дату в точности до миллисекунды, что позволяет системе понимать какую миграцию в какой очередности делать, если вы сделаете изменения через sql файлики — вам нужно будет решить проблему очереди, например когда новый сотрудник из ГИТ захочет развернуть проект, в какой очередности ему их грузить?

Comment: Я хочу еще раз подчеркнуть, что "Миграции" - это идея/концепция. Как существует паттерн проектирования MVC, так и тут. В доказательство этому - у каждого фреймворка своя реализация миграций, свои названия файлов миграции (может быть и время или просто инкремент); свои механизмы накатов-откатов и свои апи. Как плюс стоит выделить то, что разработчики внутри одного фреймворка имеют один стандарт для этого механизма и следовательно не надо разбираться в механизме. P.S. 2ой пункт лично мне не понятен.

Comment: @Manitikyl  этот вариант родился у меня с одним заказчиком, у него три проекта было на трех  разных ЦМС, и очень похожи, я перенес для начала на одну ЦМС (фреймворк не про него и нет готовности платить, и понимания, и вообще...), потом объеденил разницу функционала и настроил ГИТ, деплой и миграции соотвтетственно......... ТАк чделал ,чтобы после меня все работало и без ГИТ/Деплоя (если придет такой «спец» ) и чтобы мне было удобно все раскатывать через автодеплой

Comment: @Manitikyl  абсолютно с вами согласен на счет «идея/концепция» и не настаиваю на внедрении в том виде, как описал, а просто объяснил что и как. Если объяснил не очень абстрактно (= верно), то прошу конечно прощения, старался на примерах и на понятном языке

Comment: Претензий нет) я все понял.