# Веб-разработка с нескольких компьютеров

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Недавно купил ноутбук и возник вопрос: как вести разработку веб-приложения с двух компьютеров? Локально обновляю все данные через git, это понятно, но как быть с базой данных? Использовать удаленную БД (если так то где их удобно можно создавать в большом количестве?)? У кого какой опыт разработки с нескольких ПК? Буду рад если поделитесь.

Comment: Внешний SSD может для базы? Хотя странно, лучше уже всю работу на одном железе делать.

Comment: Так на одном не получается, дома стационар, когда не дома работаю на ноуте. Да и в целом интересно как разработчики организовывают работу между двумя компьютерами (к примеру офисный и домашний).

Comment: Юзают сервер и работают с любых компов. Интернет в наше время есть на любом гаджете.

Comment: База не должна иметь значение при разработке. А если она имеет значение, то скорее всего вы делаете что-то не так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант:
использовать сервер;

Второй вариант:
ходить с дампом, но это так себе идея;

Третий вариант:
использовать sqlite3;

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, вы можете использовать концепцию `миграций` как способ хранения изменений бд в git.

[В чем смысл миграций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817914/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)